# Downloaded SVG turns to blacksquare when opened with Illustrator and other editors

Tags: svg, qr-code

I'm using [qr-code-styling](https://github.com/kozakdenys/qr-code-styling) to generate QR codes. Once I download an SVG file and try to open it with something other than a browser or Figma, it turns into a black square when I import it for instance in Adobe Illustrator or Photoshop. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Bellow is sample SVG generated with the library:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T1l1U1RDdnMFEIDIDg5sKZuxk-6ODLG8/view?usp=sharing

It's expected to be open normally on Photoshop or Illustrator

[That's how it looks when importing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQtCs.png)

Comment: I see that the first rect, the one with a fill="white" has also a clip-path where the clipPath #clip-path-background-color is missing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The file loads fine in Adobe XD. What is your use case for editing the SVG once generated? Do you need to further process these files in some automation chain, or is this a one-off task? The SVG created by the library is horribly inefficient. It'd be far better not to use clip paths at all, since they are mapping each individual pixel already in the QR code (approx 390 paths). Move all the paths out of <defs> and delete the <clipPath> wrappers and the QR loads fine in Photoshop/pea.